# Modify the raw url of Django request before all the normal processes

Tags: django, ios6, cookieless

This can be a little tricky and I'm not sure if it's correct way. Since iOS6 prevent setting cookie in the web container, my legacy HTML5 Django game which rely much on cookie (session id) won't work again. I am trying the cookieless way, write a middleware to bring the sessid out from the url and save it to request.cookies['sess_id']. I works, but the codebase contains alot url dependent logics which are impossible to change one by one... url may look like,

```
    GET /sess_e4b817ee8993bdcbc34733feb18951ff/m/stage/quest/
```

now I'm thinking about remove the sess part from the url to make it back to

```
    GET /m/stage/quest/
```

and all the on-going process will need no change. I guess I can modified the original property of the django request object. Which property to modify? any other better idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final way I adopt is to change the iOS container to accept cookie, and  no need to change the server side any more. some code for reference,

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {    
isInternetconnectionUp = [self checkInternetConnection];
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just re-include your URLs with a prefix, no need to change anything.

```
url(r'^(?P<sessionid>sess_[a-f0-9]+)/', include('your_urls')),
```

Comment: this is a way to do it. actually I'be done it by 
(r'^(?:sess_\w*\/)?m/', include('website.urls')), but the problem is there's alot code doing things like "if url.startwith('/m/'): ...", that's why I'm seeking a method to recover the url to '/m/abcd/...'

Comment: Hm. That sounds like it's doing something that your URL routing should be doing. It might be quicker to re-write your methods not to check components of the URL.

Comment: Finally I overwrite the request.path and request.pathinfo in the middle ware when it finds the sess_id infomation. seems working fine, still in test, thanks.