# iOS6 getting and setting cookie to a UIWebView

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, ios6

I have a HTML5 web app using cookie for authentication. In iOS6 it face some problem receiving cookie from server that the outbound request will not have cookie inside header as before. I come up with idea to request session id from a http request, and put into some where (maybe NSHTTPCookieStorage?) and then all request from UIWebView will contain cookie, then most of the html5 code don't have to change..

Is it the correct way to go? if yes, how to implement this? thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in iOS6. There's a cookie sent back in the Set-Cookie response header, but this cookie isn't actually being set by mobile safari. I can see it in the response header, but not in the cookie collection.

Comment: you can checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533934/modify-the-raw-url-of-django-request-before-all-the-normal-processes it's my final solution used on a UIWebView.